# With Unified Kernel Images, how are custom initrd scenarios (such as multipath boot) addressed?

Tags: kernel, secure-boot, multipath-storage

I was looking at the Fedora change set for 38 and saw [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Unified_Kernel_Support_Phase_1) which seems like a neat idea but I was wondering how this affects systems that need custom files to be present in the initrd. One example is booting from a multipath device where the multipath configuration needs to already be present when it goes to setup the root filesystem. I'm sure there are others though.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Much appreciated :) I think you could more expressively say that you wonder how you'll convert your example to something that *can be done with a unikernel/uni-initrd*; because I'd still answer your title question with "well, not at all!", though I now understand you mean to ask how to migrate such scenarios away from actually needing a modified initrd.

Comment: I was more trying to prompt people to give a more detail accounting for the work (if any) that is being done with unified kernels to address these scenarios or if they're just considered out-of-scope to where using a custom initrd will continue to just be how you do these things.There's a Pid Eins post about mkosi but I don't know if that's what distros are actually going to do or not.

Comment: Well, I must admit that I can only guess here, but: if your system really needs dm-mp to boot and mount the root filesystem, then there's not much sense in trying to put that into a uni-initrd: there's just too many things that need to be explicitly configured, as far as I can tell (but I've never set up a dm-mp system myself, so maybe I'm wrong and there's a way to autoconfigure all this). It might be a desirable goal to make it easy for a data center operator to just generate an RPM that contains a specific, signed, bespoke initrd and install that as unikernel.

Answer (score 1):

Custom initrd scenarios are explicitly not addressed; as mentioned in the change description,

> Supporting unified kernels for all use cases quickly is not realistic though. Too many features are depending on the current workflow with a host-specific initrd (and host-specific kernel command line), which is fundamentally incompatible with unified kernels where everybody will have the same initrd and command line.

The initial goal is booting systems with a “standard” configuration: virtual machines, including in the cloud, and some physical machines with common setup.

This plan isn’t intended to handle all cases, even in the long term; [separate initrds aren’t going away](https://lwn.net/ml/fedora-devel/0538905b214dd1111d33e00ac8cb571c1bb81519.camel@redhat.com/).